# Check reserved word for text field in magento system.xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

how i can check or validated the text field which i declare in magento system.xml i mean when i enter the word in text field and press save config button the it will show message "this is reserved word".
where i can call or set this function for system.xml text field.over code is.

```
public function isReserveWord($word) {

    $is_reserved = false;
    $reserve_words = array('supportportal','view','search','askquestion');
    if (in_array($word,$reserve_words)) {
    $is_reserved = true;}
    return $is_reserved;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can manage with system.xml to make you own form in your extension

here i can give you very good document link which will very useful to you

http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_config_validation

just understand carefully and you can definitely achieve this by server side validation.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @FarmanUllah welcome,i would be glad if you will accept and vote up my answer. so some one can use it in future reference.